# How to write a macro that receives any number of arguments and print them out?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define-syntax prnt 
  (syntax-rules ()
               [(prnt elem ...) (display (format "~a" elem ...))]
               ))
```

The above code run in racket will emit the following error:

> format: format string requires 1 arguments, given 3; arguments were:
>   "~a" "1" 2 3

then how can I achieve when use (prnt "1" 2 3), it can print any thing following prnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a macro:

```
(define-syntax prnt 
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(prnt elem ...)
     (begin (displayln elem) ...)]))
```

You don't need a macro if all you want is being able to display multiple objects with a single function call, though:

```
(define (prnt . args)
  (for-each displayln args))
```

Comment: I just seldom get the macro syntax work as I want, so I just want to take this little example to get more understanding of it. and I just tested it a little bit: `((lambda v (display v)) elem ...)` as the macro template works too:)

Comment: Well, if you want to practice reading syntax-rules macros, here are a couple more templates that should work: `(display (list elem ...))` (which is about equivalent to your solution); `(begin (begin (display elem) (display " ")) ...)`.  Oh, and of course, the recursive macro variant: `(define-syntax prnt (syntax-rules () [(_) (void)] [(_ e1 e2 ...) (begin (displayln e1) (prnt e2 ...))]))`. :)

Comment: Using `map` in that last example is bad -- should be `for-each`.

Comment: @Eli: I've been guilty of reaching for `map` instead of `for-each`, because of code golfing contests I've entered (where small size is the only thing to optimise for, not speed or memory usage). I do have to remember to stop using golfing techniques when writing real code though. ;-)

Comment: For the record, for anyone who asks why `for-each` is better than `map` in this context: 1. `for-each` processes the list items left-to-right; `map` makes no such guarantees. 2. `for-each` doesn't build a result list (which in this case is just thrown away anyway). 3. In R6RS onwards, "unspecified value" can be zero or more values, not a single value, so `map` could fail when used with functions that return "unspecified value" (such as `display`).

Comment: The actual context here was Racket, so the order argument against ‘map‘ and the unspecified number of return values from ‘for-each‘ don't hold.  But the important point here is the return type, and the fact that you really don't care what you get from such a function since it's only for side effects.  (Pity that R*RS still doesn't give you such a value...)